# php more than one condition is true

Tags: php, if-statement

There are multiple variables say `$a,$b,$c,$d` having boolean value.
So what i am trying to do is .

```
if($a){echo 1;}
if($b){echo 2;}
if($c){echo 3;}
if($d){echo 4;}
and so on.. 50 variables
```

is there any better way to do this?
Note: More than one variable can be true.

Comment: Loop through the variables in order and echo the current number of iterations if true. This is exactly what loops are for.

Comment: [Arrays?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: you can use array if possible and then add conditions with foreach loop or other loop

Answer (score 1):

Maybe put all boolean variable inside an boolean array, and iterate the array to check the value

```
$boolArray = array();
$boolArray[0] = array($a, 1);
$boolArray[1] = array($b, 2);
$boolArray[2] = array($c, 3);


...

for($x = 0; $x < count($boolArray); $x++) {
  if ($boolArray[x][1]) {  
     echo (string)$boolArray[x][2];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to iterate :

```
$a= $b = $c = TRUE;
$array = array(0=> $a,1=>$b,2=> $c);
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if($value){
      echo $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this.

```
<?php
# Define the settings you already have
$a = true;
$b = true;
$c = true;

# Create an array with letters from a to z
# Instead of this, you can create an array of field names like array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$options    = range('a', 'z');

# Loop in the letters from above
foreach($options as $id => $letter) {

    # Check if variable exists and boolean is true
    if(isset(${$letter}) && ${$letter} === true) {

        # Output number from id
        echo $id + 1;
    }
}
?>
```